# Any similar tools like nmap for port scanning and finger printing OS

Tags: linux, nmap

I have an assignment to do at school. They asked us to take 2 tools that has port scanning and finger printing and compare there results.

I got the one tool nmap do you know any other?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wish this link would help you.

[tools for hacker](http://www.theprohack.com/2009/10/7-must-have-tools-for-every-hacker.html?m=1)